# Cannot reinitialise DataTable gets initialised twice for table id and non-existent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I came across a weird problem with DataTables. Not sure how this is happening.

I have this general code in the footer javascript codes which is globally available for the whole site.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 25
    ... other codes here
});
```

And in another page I have below code. (I wanted to initialise a new DataTable for this page as it needed some different settings)

HTML Code:-

```
<table id="product-catalog-datatable"
       class="table table-hover table-responsive">
```

JS Code(Specific to this page only):-

```
$('#product-catalog-datatable').DataTable({
  ....other codes here
```

The problem is, somehow even though my product index page table does not have the class `datatable` the global DataTable function gets initialised to my `product-catalog-datatable` table as well as page specific `DataTable()` function.

I am getting this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=product-catalog-datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Not sure how this is happening. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is due to conflicting DataTable initializations on the same table element. When you call `$('.datatable').dataTable({...})` globally, it applies to all elements with the class datatable. However, when you call `$('#product-catalog-datatable').DataTable({...})` specifically for the `#product-catalog-datatable` table, it initializes another DataTable on the same table.

You can try this:

Remove the global DataTable initialization and apply it only to the specific tables where it is needed. Modify your global code to exclude the #product-catalog-datatable table.
JS Code (Global):

```
$('table.datatable:not(#product-catalog-datatable)').DataTable({
  "autoWidth": false,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  "iDisplayLength": 25
  // ...other codes here
});
```

JS Code (Specific to the #product-catalog-datatable page):

```
$('#product-catalog-datatable').DataTable({
  // ...other codes here
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I do not have the `datatable` class in this table. That is the problem I am having.

Comment: Instead of using the class "datatable", use a different class or ID to target it separately. Then initialize DataTables with this specific class or ID